# Prove that there isn't a continuous bijection $f:S^1 \to S^2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Prove that there isn't a continuous bijection $f:S^1 \to S^2$

I know how to show that there isn't such an homeomorphism, removing 2 points and showing that one space remains connected while the other doesn't. But how do we prove this slightly more general claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous bijection where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff then $f$ is a homeomorphism. Indeed, it is sufficient to show that $f$ preserves closed sets. If $A\subseteq X$ is closed then it is also compact, and by continuity $f(A)$ is a compact subset of $Y$. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, it follows that $f(A)$ is closed in $Y$.

Now just use this in your case, as $S^1$ is compact and $S^2$ is Hausdorff.